# time slots range false in momentjs

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I have a loop which gets time rages in which i will be not available

like:

```
{'start'=>'06:00 pm','end'=>'08:00 am'} // i will be not available after 6PM
{'start'=>'09:00 am','end'=>'11:00 am'} // i will be not available b/w this range
```

what i am doing is running a loop of full day with 30 minutes interval if my given time dosen't came in given ranges it will show that i am available on that time.

My code:

```
    function isInBlockRange(blockdata,time)
    {

        var tReturn = false;
        if(blockdata.length>0)
        {
            var currentTime = moment(time,'hh:mm a');
            for(var i = 0; i < blockdata.length; i++){

                var BlockTimseStart = moment(blockdata[i].start,'HH:mm a');
                var BlockTimseEnd   = moment(blockdata[i].end,'HH:mm a');

                if ( (BlockTimseStart.hour() >=12 && BlockTimseEnd.hour() <=12 ) || BlockTimseEnd.isBefore(BlockTimseStart) )
                {
                    BlockTimseEnd.add(1, "days");       // handle spanning days endTime

                    if (currentTime.hour() <=12 )
                    {
                        currentTime.add(1, "days");       // handle spanning days currentTime
                    }
                }


                if(currentTime.isBetween(BlockTimseStart,BlockTimseEnd, null, '[)') == false)
                {

                    tReturn = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    tReturn = true;
                }


            }
            return tReturn;     
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

//// calling method in loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
  time = moment(time, 'hh:mm A').add((30), 'm').format('hh:mm A');
  if(isInBlockRange(blockTimeArray,time) == false){
    console.log("available");
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: if `currentTime = 09:00` am its returning `false` it and i am expecting `true`